# Cannot run @QuarkusTest annotated unit tests with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, quarkus

I cannot run `@QuarkusTest` annotated unit tests with IntelliJ IDEA. I get the following error:

```
org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.TestInstantiationException: TestInstanceFactory [io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension] failed to instantiate test class [coza.ipcm.api.mailer.control.MailerServiceTest]: io/quarkus/security/spi/AdditionalSecuredClassesBuildIem

    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstanceFactory(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:300)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:275)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassTestDescriptor.java:77)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:258)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:252)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:251)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:29)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:106)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:75)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/quarkus/security/spi/AdditionalSecuredClassesBuildIem
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.util.ServiceUtil.classesNamedIn(ServiceUtil.java:31)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader.loadStepsFrom(ExtensionLoader.java:206)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader.loadStepsFrom(ExtensionLoader.java:133)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor.run(QuarkusAugmentor.java:88)
    at io.quarkus.runner.RuntimeRunner.run(RuntimeRunner.java:114)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.doJavaStart(QuarkusTestExtension.java:249)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.createTestInstance(QuarkusTestExtension.java:394)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstanceFactory(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:285)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.quarkus.security.spi.AdditionalSecuredClassesBuildIem
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
    ... 57 more
```

I can run these tests perfectly fine with `mvn test` as well as with TestRunner in VS Code.
I have the latest versions of IDE and have the same issue on both Windows and Mac.
I can also run Spring Boot unit tests perfectly fine as well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Steps to make it work:
- Enable Quarkus bundled plugin
- Uninstall quarkus-tools plugin
- Close IntelliJ and delete IntelliJ project configuration files (.idea/, .iml)
- Import a project to IntelliJ again

Comment: I have done all that. Even tried older and not yet released versions of IDEA. Have been using IntelliJ for years and first time I get this. Quarkus plugins are in place.

Comment: Maybe you have also quarkus-tools plugin installed? If so, try without it

Comment: Just done that. Uninstalled Quarkus Tools. Same problem. Also removed Quarkus Bundled. Same problem. Its the weirdest thing.

Comment: I had the same problem, and I remember clearly that it started working after removing intellij files from the project and import as maven project again. My current setup: quarkus-tools plugin not installed, and Quarkus bundled plugin is enabled, and the tests are working. Maybe try removing Idea files from the project again after enabling Quarkus plugin... :\

Comment: Worked for me as well! Removed Quarkus Tools plug in and delted both .idea and .iml and open the project again and it works.

Comment: BTW, I've linked this SO question to Quarkus Google Groups https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/quarkus-dev/625k7XvRFCw

Answer (score 0):

After updating Quarkus to newer version and getting problem
( ..NoSuchMethodException: io.quarkus.test.common.TestResourceManager.(java.lang.Class, java.lang.Class, java.util.List, boolean, java.util.Map) )
I've used steps below in JetBrains IDEA (v.2021 and above):

- Disable (Apply button) and then again Enable (Apply button) for 'Quarkus plugin' bundled with IDEA
- File -> Invalidate caches...(check boxes: #2 Clear VCS Log caches/indedex #3 Clear downloaded shared indexes)