# Cannot start Quarkus test via IntelliJ Java IDE

Tags: java, intellij-idea, quarkus

I have a running Quarkus application with some simple Tests. When I run the tests via command line everything works. But when I run one test class via IntelliJ IDE I get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.index(java.io.InputStream)'

    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.throwBootFailureException(QuarkusTestExtension.java:625)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.interceptTestClassConstructor(QuarkusTestExtension.java:696)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.InvocationInterceptor.interceptTestClassConstructor(InvocationInterceptor.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:62)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestClassConstructor(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:363)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:310)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassTestDescriptor.java:79)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:286)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:278)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:277)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:105)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.index(java.io.InputStream)'
    at io.quarkus.test.common.TestClassIndexer$1.visitFile(TestClassIndexer.java:110)
```

Here is my maven `pom.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.liquido</groupId>
  <artifactId>liquido-backend-quarkus</artifactId>
  <version>0.2.0-BETA</version>
  <properties>
    <compiler-plugin.version>3.10.1</compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>2.16.5.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
    <webauthn4j.version>0.21.1.RELEASE</webauthn4j.version>
    <skipITs>true</skipITs>
    <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M7</surefire-plugin.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-config-yaml</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-graphql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.26</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
      <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-mailer</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.webauthn4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>webauthn4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>${webauthn4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
              <goal>generate-code</goal>
              <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-parameters</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
            <!-- maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home -->
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <systemPropertyVariables>
                <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                <!-- maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home -->
              </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <!-- plugin>
        <groupId>io.smallrye</groupId>
        <artifactId>jandex-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-index</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>jandex</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin -->
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>native</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>native</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <skipITs>false</skipITs>
        <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

Small update. This happens with ANY test method. I am simply using this dummy:

```
@Test
public void dummyTest() {
    int res = 3 * 2;
    assertEquals(6, res);
}
```

#### Update 2: Maven Dependencies

[image]

Why is my test not working in IntelliJ IDE when I click on the green "play" triangle next to the test class?

#### Update 3

Seems like QuarkusTestExtension is looking for a method

`void org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.index(java.io.InputStream)`

but the method in Jandex 3.0.5.FINAL in file Indexer.java actually returns a ClassInfo:

`public ClassInfo index(InputStream stream) throws IOException { ... }`

Comment: It seems it's a regression. This [issue](https://github.com/apache/camel-quarkus/issues/4116) is almost same.

Comment: Yes I also saw this other issue. But I don't understand it?  Is that solved? Do I need to change anything? What do you mean by "regression"?

Comment: ah found some more. This could be related to the quarkus-tools plugin:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60819410/nosuchmethodexception-error-when-running-tests-after-upgrading-to-quarkus-1-3-0?rq=2

Comment: I mean there was a bug which was resolved and it appeard again. Is there any specialties in your tests? I'd like to investigate this a little bit more.

Comment: You're using Quarkus 2.x, so you should have Jandex 2.x on the classpath. For some reason, you have Jandex 3.x on the classpath -- use `mvn dependency:tree` (or maybe some IntelliJ-specific way?) to figure out why is that.

Comment: quarkus-junit5:2.16.5.Final  -> quarkus-test-common:2.16.5.Final -> jandex:3.0.5 (test)

Comment: and also quarkus-smallrye-graphql:2.16.5.Final -> smallrye-graphql-schema-builder:1.9.4 -> jandex:3.0.5 (compile)

Comment: @zforgo  No I am not doing anything special in my test cases. I added a dummyTestCase (see above). Same issue.  Yes it really seems to be related to maven dependencies ....

Comment: Ouch, I'm sorry, my bad, I totaly screwed up my answer. This is indeed an issue with wrong Jandex version on the classpath, but my previous answer is incorrect. The `Indexer.index()` method that returns `void` exists since Jandex 3.0, and Quarkus has moved to Jandex 3.0 in version 2.14. So you _should_ have Jandex 3.0 -- but you apparently have Jandex 2.x (which _doesn't_ have that method). Please look for Jandex 2.x. My apologies for confusion!

Comment: (Thank you for your support!)   There is only Jandex 3.0.5 in my dependency tree.  And according to the stacktrace it is looking for a method  `'void org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.index(java.io.InputStream)`   But the class Index.java only contains a method that returns a ClassInfo   There is no method index() without a parameter or any method index(...) that returns void in jandexer 3.0.5.

Comment: Yes, when I wrote `Indexer.index()`, I didn't mean zero-parameter method, I was just lazy to spell the parameter list :-) In Jandex 3.0, the `Indexer` class has a method `void index(InputStream stream)`, while in Jandex 2.x, it has a method `ClassInfo index(InputStream stream)`. (Technically, for binary compatibility, Jandex 3.0 also has the `ClassInfo`-returning variant, hacked in through bytecode transformation, but that's not the point.) If the JVM is complaining that it can't find the `void`-returning method, there must be Jandex 2.x on the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

## SOLVED

(Thank you so much @Ladicek and @zforgo for your great support here.)

Yes it actually was a dependency to Jandex 2.0 that came in through a "provided module dependency of IntelliJ. I am defenetily sure this dependency was not introduces through maven or pom. Somehow it must have been added in IntelliJ. (Don't know exactly how. Maybe through a plugin or something else.)

tl;dr

I strange cases like this it does help to:

1. close IntelliJ
2. delete (or backup) the .idea folder
3. re-import the maven project into IntelliJ

Comment: somehow that "provided" dependency still reapears from time to time ...???